# How do I store a string in ArrayField? (Django and PostgreSQL)

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am unable to store a string in ArrayField. There are no exceptions thrown when I try to save something in it, but the array remains empty.
Here is some code from models.py :

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
import uuid
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField, ArrayField


# Create your models here.
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=False, primary_key=True)
    api_secret = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_categories = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length = 1000), default = list)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key

class PreParentProduct(models.Model):
    product_user = models.ForeignKey(UserDetail, default=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_url = models.URLField(max_length = 1000)
    pre_product_title = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    pre_product_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    pre_product_variants_data = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pre_product_title
```

I try to save it this way:

```
        catlist = ast.literal_eval(res.text)
        for jsonitem in catlist:
            key = jsonitem.get('name')
            id = jsonitem.get("id")
            dictionary = {}
            dictionary['name'] = key
            dictionary['id'] = id
            tba = json.dumps(dictionary)
            print("It works till here.")
            print(type(tba))
            usersearch[0].user_categories.append(tba)
            print(usersearch[0].user_categories)

        usersearch[0].save()
        print(usersearch[0].user_categories)
```

The output I get is:

```
It works till here.
<class 'str'>
[]
It works till here.
<class 'str'>
[]
[]
```

Is this the correct way to store a string inside ArrayField?
I cannot store JSONField inside an ArrayField, so I had to convert it to a string.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Changes would be reflected only after `save()` right?

Comment: `usersearch[0].save()
print(usersearch[0].user_categories)`

gives 

`It works till here.
<class 'str'>
[]
It works till here.
<class 'str'>
[]
[]
`
Last `[]` shows that it is still empty. I'll update my question.

Comment: what is `usersearch`? What I wonder is whether you get back the same (python) object every time for `usersearch[0]` or does it give a new python instance loaded from the database?

Comment: I use the `key` to find the user. `usersearch` gives list of objects of class `<class 'admin_panel.models.UserDetail'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution to the append problem.

You haven't demonstrated how your `usersearch[0]` I suspect it's something like this:

```
usersearch = UserDetail.objects.all()
```

If that is so you are making changes to a resultset, those things are immutable. Try this you will see that the id is unchanged too:

```
usersearch[0].id = 1000
print usersearch.id
```

But this works

```
usersearch = list(UserDetail.objects.all())
```

and so does

```
u = usersearch[0]
```

### Solution to the real problem

```
user_categories = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length = 1000), default = list)
```

This is wrong. ArrayFields shouldn't be used in this manner. You will soon find that you need to search through them and

> Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a
>   sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row
>   for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to
>   search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements

ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/arrays.html

You need to normalize your data. You need to have a category model and your UserDetail should be related to it through a foreign key.

Comment: glad to have helped